# SQL not grouping properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to find the number of records for certain service codes, by year - in my database.

The code:

```
SELECT datepart( year,dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date) as'Year',
       dbo.PUBACC_HD.radio_service_code as 'Service Code',
       count(dbo.PUBACC_FR.transmitter_make) as 'Number of Records'

FROM dbo.PUBACC_FR 
INNER JOIN dbo.PUBACC_HD 
ON dbo.PUBACC_FR.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_HD.unique_system_identifier
GROUP BY  dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date, dbo.PUBACC_HD.radio_service_code
ORDER BY [Number of Records] desc
```

Current Result:

```
Year        Service Code Number of Records
----------- ------------ -----------------
2011        CF           11195 <----
2013        CF           2042
2011        CF           1893  <----
2013        CF           1879
2013        CF           1841
2013        CF           1741
2013        CF           1644
2010        CF           1595
2013        MG           1563
2011        CF           1512  <----
2013        CF           1510
2011        CF           1454
2011        CF           1428
2016        CF           1385
2011        CF           1378
2015        MG           1349
```

I want all of the fields to be aggregated. Example of none aggregations denoted by arrows. `(2011, CF)` is just one example in the large table of things not aggregating correctly.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Why not `GROUP BY datepart( year,dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date), dbo.PUBACC_HD.radio_service_code `?

Comment: Because you grouped by the date but you are displaying the year. Group by the year of grant_date instead of the datetime and you should be good to go.

Comment: Why should only those three `2011` records be grouped and not all of them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I was just showing an example of them not being grouped. Sorry for the slightly misleading information

Comment: Query also got issue in order by statement.. It should be like ORDER BY count(dbo.PUBACC_FR.transmitter_make) desc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
GROUP BY datepart( year,dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date)
```

instead of:

```
GROUP BY  dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date
```

As it is right now, you are grouping by a `date` value, that may differ among records sharing the same `radio_service_code` value.

Answer (score 3):

**Change Group By** To:

```
Group By datepart( year,dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date),dbo.PUBACC_HD.radio_service_code
```

You have only select year from grant_date, so you have to also write group by accordingly

Comment: Stack Won't let me mark this as an answer this fast haha! Such a simple thing I missed. Thank you so much for the quick answer

Answer (score 2):

Because you are grouping by grant_date and not by year

Answer (score 2):

Try with statement and also change your group by condition.

```
;With CTE AS
(    
    SELECT 
         datepart( year,dbo.PUBACC_HD.grant_date) as Year,
         dbo.PUBACC_HD.radio_service_code as ServiceCode,
         count(dbo.PUBACC_FR.transmitter_make) as NumberofRecords        
    FROM dbo.PUBACC_FR 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PUBACC_HD 
    ON dbo.PUBACC_FR.unique_system_identifier = dbo.PUBACC_HD.unique_system_identifier
)
Select * from cte
GROUP BY  Year, ServiceCode
ORDER BY NumberofRecords desc
```

As @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski state you are using year in select and group it by date, thats is problem.

Comment: This is actually a _very_ nice solution as it will give others an easier time to query from this. Wish both two posts could be an answer